GCC 14 update, operator= now complains about a read-only member?
I'm using a header-only raytracing library, NanoRT.
Within that file there is a class TriangleSAHPred. It has the following members:
  mutable int axis_;
  mutable T pos_;
  const T* vertices_;
  const unsigned int* faces_;
  const size_t vertex_stride_bytes_;

It also has an overload for operator=:
  TriangleSAHPred<T>& operator=(const TriangleSAHPred<T>& rhs)
  {
    axis_ = rhs.axis_;
    pos_ = rhs.pos_;
    vertices_ = rhs.vertices_;
    faces_ = rhs.faces_;
    vertex_stride_bytes_ = rhs.vertex_stride_bytes_;

    return (*this);
  }

This overload worked fine despite vertices_, faces_ and vertex_stride_bytes_ all being const.
However, as of GCC 14, this no longer works. Specifically, vertex_stride_bytes_ is a problem - the other two const members appear fine. I'd assume it's because those two are pointers, while vertex_stride_bytes_ is of type size_t.
My question: What changed in GCC14 that is causing this to break now after several years of working fine? Was it always wrong, or is something in the version of GCC14.1 I'm using wrong? Why does only vertex_stride_bytes_ cause an issue?

vertex_stride_bytes_ is const.  You can't assign to a const object.  This should have never compiled.

@NathanOliver This has compiled fine for many years. It's only as of GCC14 that it's been a problem. Why?

No clue.  It should have never compiled on any version of GCC or C++ since you are not allowed to modify const variables.

Const and reference members are evil for this exact reason. Can you produce a [mcve] that compiles on GCC 13 but not 14?

Also, the other two have never been const -- they are a non-const pointer to const data.

If const size_t vertex_stride_bytes_; was const size_t* vertex_stride_bytes_; then it would work.  Maybe that was also changed?

@NathanOliver Our copy of that library hasn't been updated in years. So no changes to that member.

So it compiles, as long as you never use the operator. Just remove it. Ask upstream to remove it. No one has ever used it, because it does not compile.

Maybe that's the change. Maybe nothing in the code actually uses that operator, so up until GCC14 it's never been compiled. But something about GCC14 is forcing it to compile even if it's not used. Thoughts? I'm amazed no-one ran into this in all these years.

Also, sometimes the descriptions of C++ features use language like "if something then the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required". It's very well possible that previous compilers didn't complain as long as nobody used the operator=, while some change in gcc14 made it complain when it's just there, even if it's not used. Either way, it never worked... unless previous gcc versions were all bugged like that, but that's unlikely since it's a very simple, everyday situation.

The bigger question is interesting: which behavior - gcc13 or gcc14 - is standard compliant? Should the compiler issue a diagnostic when operator= is used or immediately when encountering code? Has this changed? The -std=c++03 / c++11 doesn't change anything.

Here's a smaller example that reproduces this behaviour:
https://godbolt.org/z/vYrefnPYs
template<typename T>
struct TriangleSAHPred
{
  const int vertex_stride_bytes_;
  TriangleSAHPred<T>& operator=(const TriangleSAHPred<T>& rhs)
  {
    vertex_stride_bytes_ = rhs.vertex_stride_bytes_;

    return (*this);
  }
};

There is no template parameter T for which the definition for operator= would compile, since vertex_stride_bytes_ = rhs.vertex_stride_bytes_; does not depend on a template parameter and doesn't compile. This is formally "ill-formed no diagnostic required", meaning the program is invalid but a compiler doesn't have to tell you.
GCC 13 just accepted this, but would error if you ever tried to use operator=. GCC 14 is smarter and is able to see that vertex_stride_bytes_ = rhs.vertex_stride_bytes_; is not dependendent on any template parameters and can't compile, so issues a diagnostic as it's parsing the template (before any TriangleSAHPred<T> for any T are instantiated).

Out of curiosity, why would dependence on the template parameter matter?

@TylerShellberg If it were const T vertex_stride_bytes_ then there might be some type T that has an operator=(const T&) const;, but since it's not dependent, then we know that operator= is invalid for all T (which is what makes this ill-formed NDR)
